# Giving id's to dynamically created views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-custom-view

I'm a beginner in coding, and I would love some help. I want to make an alarm application. On my main page fragment, I added a button that will add an alarm into a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView. The alarm will have three TextViews in it, and a button for activation/deactivation.

Here is how I would like my alarm to look like (this is currently not being used anywhere in my coding; I created it just to have a visual aid of what I'm aiming to make):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/alarm_fl"
    android:background="@mipmap/white_box">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9.5dp"
        android:id="@+id/alarm_activation_button"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:id="@+id/alarm_time"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11.5dp"
        android:textSize="7pt"
        android:id="@+id/alarm_ampm"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="5pt"
        android:id="@+id/alarm_day"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is how I'm currently testing my alarms in the fragment:

```
addAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater alarm_inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.alarm_ll);
            View alarm_view = alarm_inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm_layout, parent);

            TextView alarm_time = (TextView) alarm_view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_time);
            alarm_time.setText("9시 45분");

            TextView alarm_ampm = (TextView) alarm_view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_ampm);
            alarm_ampm.setText("오후");

            TextView alarm_day = (TextView) alarm_view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_day);
            alarm_day.setText("월,화,수,목,금");

            Button activation_button = (Button) alarm_view.findViewById(R.id.alarm_activation_button);
            activation_button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.checkbox_deactivated);
        }
    });
```

where alarm_ll is the LinearLayout that I want to populate with newly created alarms.

And it appeared to me that I need unique id's for each of the Buttons and TextViews to manipulate them separately.

Now here are my questions:

1. Is this the right approach if I want to add views programmatically whenever the button is clicked? Or is there a better, simpler way?
2. My alarms would eventually need to be objects. Would it be possible for a non-activity class like User, or in this case Alarm, to have a layout for it's own?
3. How do I give unique id's to each view when creating via a button click?
4. When I test-run my application now, the layouts I add into alarm_ll won't be saved, so if I shift to another activity and come back, alarm_ll will be reset. How do I save these in a fragment, when they are not in primitive data types?

I'm sorry to ask so many questions at once, but I would really love some answers or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of assigning an ID to each view? What will this ID be used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I assume that you want to have the ability to set multiple alarms. This is a perfect use of `ListView` or `RecyclerView` which allows you to inflate several copies of the same view and display a list based on some underlying data.
2. I suggest that you learn about creating "model" which are objects that store the data. These "model" objects should be separate from the view objects which display the data. There are several design patterns which are commonly used for this kind of separation: Model-View-Controller, Model-View-Presenter, and Model-View-ModelView.
3. `android:id` in XML is typically used to be able to get an object for the view in the Java code. When you create a view dynamically, either the way you showed in your question or by inflating XML, you already have this object, so I do not see a need for assigning an ID to these dynamically created views.
4. When using one of the design patterns which I suggested in #2, you will also create a way to store the data. Android provides an API to store information in a database. This can easily be displayed in a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` by using an "adapter".